# Save windowhandle from p.MainWindowHandle in listview

Tags: c#, listview

I get some windowhandles from selecting processes and actualy can put them into a listbox. But since im not satisfied with the informations that gets displayed in a listbox, I decided to go with a listview.

```
private void doWindowListRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    windowListView.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses().Where(pp => pp.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && pp.ProcessName != "explorer"))
    {
        ListViewItem wlv = new ListViewItem(p.Id.ToString(),1);
        wlv.SubItems.Add(p.ProcessName);
        wlv.SubItems.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
        /* want to add a handle here. may a hidden column as well */
        windowListView.Items.Add(wlv);
    }
}
```

I have to say I'm not the C# pro! :D

So my main question is...

**Is it possible to add a windowhandle in a `listview` ?**

because I want to do some things with the selected listview information. It would be way more easy to directly retrieve the windowhandle from the listview. Not from the listview its self...

ATM I'm doing it like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string processName = windowListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        Process[] pro = Process.GetProcessesByName( processName );

    foreach(Process p in pro)
    {
        if(p.ProcessName == processName)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(processName);

            SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    }
}
```

but getting the processes all the time doesn't seems to be very good :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply need to convert the IntPtr to a string:

```
wlv.SubItems.Add(p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
```

To get back an IntPtr for `SetWindowPos`:

```
 IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(windowListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text));
 SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```